# FreeNAS Replication Issues?

Tags: truenas

Trying to test replication between two FreeNAS boxes, and one side is coming up with the following error when I try to put in the SSH:

"getaddrinfo freenas1.local: hostname nor servname provided, or not known"

I changed the hostname, and server name a couple times, reconfigured it over DHCP, and on the local netowrk. Tried assigning it a static to connect through, but it just won't connect in.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like one of the servers can't locate the other on the network. Are they both using DNS servers that are capable of resolving requests for the remote box? I'm guessing not.

Comment: We are going over IP, not DNS hosting.

Comment: Is `freenas1.local` in your question the box you're working on or the remote box?

Comment: It's the remote box.

Comment: Ok. If you're not using DNS, how is `freenas2.local` supposed to know what `freenas1.local` is?